# Are electrodes in an electrolysis unique for every electrolyte or can any random electrode be used with an electrolyte during electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electricity

For example, during the electrolysis of water, platinum electrodes are used, why can't I use any other electrode as long as they are conductors? why does some electrolysis require specific electrodes to work, instead of just any random electrode?

Comment: Electrodes - especially anodes - may corrode or even getting dissolved. E.g. neither Pt neither Au dissolve in HCl. But using them as anodes of HCl electrolysis would form [AuCl4]- and [PtCl6]^2-.

Comment: Electrolysis can be carried out with all sorts of electrodes, provided they are conductors. But the result depends on the choice of the electrodes and of the choice of electrolyte, because the electrodes can be corroded by the electrolyte and by the product of the electrolysis, as mentioned by Poutnik about $\ce{HCl}$ electrolysis.

Answer (score 1):

Any electrode will oxidize if the potential is high enough and there is nothing present that is more easily oxidized or, if given enough time, potentials are close and conditions right. We had platinum electrodes in flow meters completely vanish in water over several weeks at 10 volts potential. Someone told the engineers that platinum was not reactive. Electrode choice, composition and even shape and configuration are important. In electroplating of large objects the resistance of the electrodes means the current densities are a function of distance from the connections and must be allowed for if plating is to be uniform.